# Problem in edition MongoDB entries using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm coding a Node.js app and while trying to edit MongoDB entries, by displaying them to my front end sorting by their id - my app simply doesn't work with the following error:

(node:14987) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14987) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

**Here's the piece of code which I coded in Node.js:**

```
// Edit idea form
app.get('/ideas/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
    Idea.findOne({
        _id: req.params.id
    })
    .then(idea => {
        res.render('ideas/edit', {
            idea : idea
        });
    });
});
```

**Also, here's the edit form in handlebars/html:**

```
{{#each errors}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{text}}</div>
{{else}}


{{/each}}

<div class="card card-body">
    <h3>Edit Video Idea</h3>
    <form action="/ideas" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title"
           value="{{idea.title}}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="detais">Details</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="details" required>
                {{idea.details}}
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: try in the render function using a try catch to see better the error

Comment: Also try using async await for handling promise

Comment: Or try with The unhandledRejection Event https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection